# Error: invalid type (list) for variable when executing rlm

Tags: r, plyr

I'm trying to fit a model to each location in my dataset.  I run the following code (with a sample recreated to mirror the data I'm using):

```
library(plyr)
library(MASS)

month.abbr <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May",
     "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
month <- factor(rep(month.abbr, length = 1200), levels = month.abbr)
county_code <- sample(1:100, 1200, replace = T)
store_rev <- sample(2000:85000, 1200, replace = T)
color_levels <-c('blue', 'red', 'green')
colors <- factor(rep(color_levels, length = 1200), levels = color_levels)
data <- data.frame(month, county_code, store_rev, colors)

product_aggregate_values <-ddply(data, ~month+county_code+colors, summarise, total_rev = sum(store_rev))
deseasf <- function(total_rev) rlm(total_rev~month-1, maxit = 50)
models <- ddply(product_aggregate_values, ~county_code + colors, deseasf)
failed <- ddply(models, function(x) !x$converged)
```

And I get the following error:

```
Error: invalid type (list) for variable 'total_rev'
```

I think it might be because I am using product_aggregate_values as a data.frame, but when I try to create it using daply and adjust the code accordingly, I receive the following error:

```
Error in splitter_a(.data, .margins, .expand) : 
'pairlist' object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'
Error in inherits(.data, "split") : object 'models' not found
```

Comment: Please take the time to make your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Provide a sample `data` object so we know what types of objects you are working with. Ideally we would be able to copy/paste your code into R and get the same error as you. That will make it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `deseasf` function. What get's passed in is the subsetted data.frame, not just the `total_rev` vector. You should use that as your `data=` parameter to `rlm`. That function should be

```
deseasf <- function(x) rlm(total_rev~month-1, data=x, maxit = 50)
```

this will actually still produce an error with your test data because you are trying to estimate a coefficient for every month and you only have one value per month so you get a a "perfect" which `rlm()` actually complains about. Hopefully it will work on your real data.